# How to create row for Google's calendar graph api from JSON Object

Tags: php, json, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I received JSON Object in my console as follows:
[image]

and I want to convert this **JSON Object** so that I will pass this to Google's calendar graph API's **addRows()** function.

My Script is as follows:

```
function drawChart() {
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
   dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
   dataTable.addRows([
        //HERE TO ADD DATA LIKE [new Date(2017, 09, 19),9],[new Date(2017, 09, 20),9]
    ]);

   var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

   var options = {
     title: "Daily hours utilization",
     height: 350,
   };

   chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

So basically I want to convert

> {today_date: "2017-09-19", hours: "9"}

To

> [ new Date(2017, 9, 19), 9 ],

and Output like [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're looking to convert the date string into a date object.

One method of achieving this would be to loop over your json data structure and build a rows array from that. Once this loop has finished you can pass the rows array to the **addRows** method.

Lets assume your json data structure is stored in a variable called **$jsonData**

```
//Store processed rows in this array
$rows = [];

//Sample json data structure (pull yours from the source)
$jsonData = [
    {
    today_date: "2017-09-19",
    hours: "9"
  },
  {
    today_date: "2017-09-20",
    hours: "9"
  },
];

//Loop over every object within the json data, parsing the date string and
//creating a date object from it.
//Add the date object and the hours field to the rows array
$jsonData.forEach(function($data){
    $dateElements = $data.today_date.split("-");
    $rows.push([
      new Date($dateElements[0], $dateElements[1], $dateElements[2]),
      $data.hours
  ]);
});

//Using your code above, add the rows
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
dataTable.addRows($rows);
```

I have created a little jsfiddle so you can see the output of the rows array from my test data: https://jsfiddle.net/JParkinson1991/aukwxo6L/

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: From Abhijit Kumbhar

With help of your guideline I edited my code and it works fine now, some changes I did they are as follows:

**Final solution:**

```
function drawChart() {
    var rows =[];

    jsDailyCount.forEach(function(data){
        var dateElements = data.today_date.split("-");
        rows.push([
            new Date(dateElements[0], dateElements[1], dateElements[2]),
            parseFloat(data.hours)
        ]);
    });

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'hours' });
    dataTable.addRows(rows);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
    var options = {
        title: "Daily hours utilization",
        height: 350,
    };
   chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: @Abhijit Kumbhar i tweaked your edit, to remove unecessary code from your final solution. Worth taking a look it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = {today_date: "2017-09-19", hours: "9"};
var m = s.hours;
var d = s.today_date.split("-");
alert(d[0] + " " + d[1] + " " + d[2] + " " + m);
```

Instead of alerting, use those values in your script.